# What is the exact version library for pdf view in android studio 3.1.3? implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'

Tags: pdf, dependencies, viewer, pdfviewer

When I put a library for pdf view in dependencies in android studio 3.1.3 ,It shows the error message "All com.android.support libraries  must use the exact same version specification ".What is the way to read pdf in this situation?

build.gradle file has the following code:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lenovo.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the actual versions of the dependencies that Gradle is using during the config phase?  `gradlew dependencies` will do that, though it is unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I wanted to  read pdf in an android app.To do so I add a line to dependencies of build.gradle.The line is: implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
But,it does not work. There was a message"All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification(mixing versions can lead to runtime errors)"                                       My build.gradle file has the exact same code provided in the above portion.In this situation, which line of code is needed to add or remove for avoiding this error and to read the pdf file existed in my app.

Comment: One of your transitive dependencies is causing a problem at config time when all the versions are resolved. The first thing to do is find the offending dependency. Have to inspected the dependencies with the command I provided? Then you might be able to manage that dependency to force it to be at a specific version. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html